After a successful payment on Razorpay, my CSS is being removed on my Next.js 14 page router and i have to reload whole page to fetch CSS again
After a successful payment transaction processed through Razorpay, I've encountered an unexpected issue where the CSS styling on my Next.js 14 page router is being removed or affected. This issue occurs intermittently and seems to coincide with the completion of the payment process. I'm unsure why this is happening and how the payment process is interacting with the CSS styling of my Next.js application. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated
I attempted to utilize the useRouter hook in order to implement a page reload within my Next.js application but still i have to load whole page again

Facing the same issue. Were you able to figure it out?
